# How to get my prop value to display either "importing" or "current" if the prop number is 1 or 0?

Tags: if-statement, react-props, storybook

I'm trying to get this prop (status), which will either have a value of 1 or 0, to display either "importing" or "current" instead of just displaying the 1 or 0.

Because I'm not using State or setState and not defining a constant, I'm not sure how to set up an if statement to display the desired text. I am using React and Storybook. This component is separate from the rest of the table, for reusability purposes. Here is the code for each table row.

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { GiCloudDownload } from "react-icons/gi";
import { FaAngleDoubleRight } from "react-icons/fa";
import { MdClose } from "react-icons/md";

export const BidType = ({
  id,
  airline,
  fleet,
  seat,
  domicile,
  status,
  numBidPeriods,
  importedOn,
}) => {
  return (
    <tr className="align-middle">
      <td>{id}</td>
      <td>
        {seat} {domicile} {fleet}
      </td>
      <td className="text-center">{status}</td>
      <td className="text-center">{numBidPeriods}</td>
      <td className="text-center">{importedOn}</td>
      <td className="d-grid gap-2 ">
        <button className="btn btn-primary btn-sm bg-light">
          <GiCloudDownload /> Retry Import
        </button>
        <button className="btn btn-primary btn-sm bg-light" disabled>
          Bid Periods <FaAngleDoubleRight />
        </button>
        <button className="btn btn-primary btn-sm bg-light" disabled>
          Import History <FaAngleDoubleRight />
        </button>
        <button className="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
          <MdClose /> Delete
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
};

BidType.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.number,
  airline: PropTypes.string,
  fleet: PropTypes.string,
  seat: PropTypes.string,
  domicile: PropTypes.string,
  status: PropTypes.number,
  numBidPeriods: PropTypes.number,
  importedOn: PropTypes.string,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do an if else condition before your return to check if status === 1 or 0.
After that you can display what you want depending on the result in the form of a string for example :

```
const textToDisplayInsteadOfStatus = status === 1 ? "importing" :"current";
```

You just have to display the result in your return

```
<td className="text-center">{textToDisplayInsteadOfStatus}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done like below:

```
{status === 0 && <td className="text-center">importing</td>}
{status === 1 && <td className="text-center">current</td>}
```

For more details you should study about conditional rendering [here](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html).